# Magento2: How can I fetch the email transaction grid collection in my custom extension?

Tags: magento2, collection, email-templates, transactional-mail

I am working on one custom module and **I need to fetch the transactional email templates** grid which is at Marketing > email templates in magento 2 default.
I need that grid in my custom extension, how can i get that?

---

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First you will have to inject the `Magento\Email\Model\ResourceModel\Template\CollectionFactory` class in your constructor:

```
protected $emailTemplateCollectionFactory;


public function __construct(
        ...
        \Magento\Email\Model\ResourceModel\Template\CollectionFactory $emailTemplateCollectionFactory
) {
        ...
        $this->emailTemplateCollectionFactory= $emailTemplateCollectionFactory;
        ...

}
```

Then you can create the collection by calling:

```
$collection = $this->emailTemplateCollectionFactory->create();
```

Comment: This seems to be working, but how can I get the id and title of the email template in separate array? Thank you in advance,

Comment: @GauravJain when you loop through your collection you can call `->getTemplateId()` to get the id and `->getTemplateCode`  to get the title

Comment: Can you provide the sample code for foreach loop? Because when we try foreach loop, it only prints first record data. If print whole collection then only it shows all records in log but not in foreach loop.

Comment: @GauravJain you can do `foreach ($collection as $template) { $id = $template->getTemplateId(); $title = $template->getTemplateCode(); }`

Comment: Thanks for the code, I am trying the code but it is giving me blank data in log file.

Comment: how we can get New invoice template List ?